# Microservice can not reach Elasticsearch Image

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, microservices, jhipster

I have one Microservice with Jhipster version 5v and a image 2.4.1 of the ElasticSearch running in vagrant centos 7v. The two image are running but the operations of save and search can not reach the Elasticsearch image.

docker-compose:

```html
service-app:
    image: "..."
    depends_on:
      - service-mysql
      - service-elasticsearch
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
      - jhipster-registry
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,swagger
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:admin@jhipster-registry:8761/config
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://service-mysql:3306/service?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
      - SPRING_DATA_CASSANDRA_CONTACTPOINTS=cassandra
      - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
      - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_HOST=jhipster-logstash
      - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_PORT=5000
      - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER-NAME=SERVICE
      - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=service-elasticsearch:9300
      - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_BROKERS=kafka
      - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_ZK_NODES=zookeeper
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:admin@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
    ports:
      - 60088:8088
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m"
        max-file: "10"

  service-elasticsearch:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - service-elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
    environment:
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - cluster.name=service
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - CLUSTER_NAME=SERVICE
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100m" 
        max-file: "10"
```

application_dev.yml:

```html
    data:
        elasticsearch:
            properties:
                path:
                    home: target/elasticsearch
```

application_prod:

```html
    data:
        jest:
            uri: http://localhost:9200
```

domain:

Comment: did you verify the ES running

Comment: Yes, i check the logs and is running,but does not react when it is done operations.
It's always print this: "[2019-07-04 11:27:20,746][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Gaia] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2019-07-04 11:27:50,747][WARN ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Gaia] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [eZvec2BWSuuyDYdi8OrdQA][Gaia][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/SERVICE/nodes/0] free: 2.2gb[5.4%], shards will be relocated away from this node"

Comment: were u able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that one of your ES node in your cluster is running on low disk space, hence you are getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289024/high-disk-watermark-exceeded-even-when-there-is-not-much-data-in-my-index) exception.

Please make sure that you as clean up the disk space on the ES nodes on which you are getting the exception. I have faced this issue 2-3 times and **it does not depend on the Elasticsearch index size**, hence even you might have a very small index on large disk(let's suppose 2 TB) but if you don't have a free disk space more than 10% (which is almost 200 GB, which is huge) still you will get this exception and you need to clean up your disk space.